# Use url.URL with controller-gen

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubebuilder

I'm trying to develop a custom resource on kubernetes with kubebuilder.
In this CR, I have a field of type `url.URL`

I get this error :

```
(*in).DeepCopyInto undefined (type *url.URL has no field or method DeepCopyInto)
```

Is there a way to work with type `url.URL` when developing a CR ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solution
I don't know if it's the best but I've created a custom type URL with the part which is missing to use `net/url` with `controller-gen`.

It works fine
https://gist.github.com/quentinalbertone/ec00085b57992d836c08d4586295ace7